# how to use for loop in tensorflow/keras when using tf.keras functional API?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I wish to modify the CuDNNGRU Output with for loop. However, it seems like I can't do so due to the tf.GradientTape graph mode. How can I modify the CuDNNGRU in Functional API? I know that normally we can perform some matrix ops on the functional API with tf.keras.backend.* functions like K.backend.batch_dot etc. However, I have to do some complex ops like triple for loop or more, etc., If someone knows how to do so, please help!

```
.....source code
x = L.Lambda(lambda fm: tf.squeeze(fm, axis=1))(x)
gru_1 = CuDNNGRU(512, return_sequences=True, name='gru1')(x)
gru_1b = CuDNNGRU(512, return_sequences=True, go_backwards=True,name='gru1_b')(x)
for i in gru_1:
    .....apply some function to gru_1 outputs
```

By the way, I currently try to modify the GRU outputs with below code.

```
def attention(inputs):
    transpose_input = tf.transpose(inputs,perm=[0,2,1])
    atten_w = K.backend.batch_dot(inputs,transpose_input)
    atten_w = tf.linalg.set_diag(atten_w,tf.zeros(tf.shape(atten_w)[0:-1],dtype=tf.float32))
    atten_w = tf.nn.softmax(atten_w,axis=1)
    atten_v = tf.py_function(calculate_atten,inp=[inputs,atten_w],Tout=[tf.float32])
    atten_v = tf.convert_to_tensor(atten_v)
    atten_v.set_shape(self.input_shapex)


def calculate_atten(data,atten_w):
    input_vector = data.numpy()
    atten_vectors = atten_w.numpy()
    all_batch = []
    for index,one_batch in enumerate(input_vector):
        tmp_w = atten_vectors[index]
        all_vector = []
        for j,vector in enumerate(one_batch):
            tmp = np.zeros(input_vector.shape[2])
            for w in tmp_w[j]:
                tmp += vector*w
            all_vector.append(tmp)
        all_batch.append(all_vector)
    return all_batch
```

However, the above code, the tf.py_function return [time,features] instead of [batch,time,features], if this can be done, i can use tf.py_function to build a layer. But it seems like can't, HELP!!!!

## Update

I have been able to achieve the ops, with nested tf.map_fn. Although it needs to think properly what to pass to tf.map_fn(multiple inputs must be return in multiple output). Hope this can help others

```
def attn_transformation(inputs):
    inputs_transpose = tf.transpose(inputs)
    atten_w = tf.tensordot(inputs,inputs_transpose,axes=1)
    def transform(data):
        multiply_data = data[0]*data[1][...,tf.newaxis]
        return [multiply_data,data[1]]
    data = tf.map_fn(lambda x:transform(x),elems=([inputs,atten_w]))
    data = tf.reduce_sum(data[0],axis=1)
    return data

gru_1 = CuDNNGRU(512, return_sequences=True, name='gru1')(x)
gru_1b = CuDNNGRU(512, return_sequences=True, go_backwards=True,name='gru1_b')(x)
atten_vf = L.Lambda(lambda x: tf.map_fn(attn_transformation,x))(gru_1)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For any arbitrary operation where you want to apply it to every `i` in `tensor` you can just use `tf.map_fn()`

So for example, we can do something like:

```py
inp = Input(shape=(2,3))
gru = CuDNNGRU(512, return_sequences=True)(inp)

def dummy_operation_to_be_applied(row):
  return row + 1

out = Lambda(lambda x: tf.map_fn(dummy_operation_to_be_applied, x))(gru)
```

UPDATE:

Note that we can also nest `tf.map_fn()` to map operations across lower dimensions too.

For example:

```py
def nested_op(x):
  return tf.reduce_max(x) + x

def dummy_operation_to_be_applied(row):
  return tf.map_fn(nested_op, row)

out = Lambda(lambda x: tf.map_fn(dummy_operation_to_be_applied, x))(gru)
```

Comment: Thank you for reply, for simple task , this can be done with above code, however what I really want to do is something like for loop the "row". I tried this but it show this error.
TypeError: You are attempting to use Python control flow in a layer that was not declared to be dynamic. Pass `dynamic=True` to the class constructor.
Encountered error:
"""
Tensor objects are only iterable when eager execution is enabled. To iterate over this tensor use tf.map_fn.
"""

Comment: You can just nest them. Use `tf.map_fn` again inside the operation

Comment: @Leow I updated the answer with an example of nesting calls to `tf.map_fn`

Comment: Thank you for replying! I have been able to do my ops, however it quite troublesome, when I using the tf.map_fn that have multiple input but single input.  tf.map_fn need to be same shape as it's input.